# Hiding/Showing Divs (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

Hi I have this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/BcFVv/

I am trying to show only 1 Div at a time instead of all three. I want it so a certain div will only show when itss button is pressed.

As you can see it shows all of the Divs at the start. The buttons work fine.

QUESTION: How do I hide Divs 2 and 3 from the start?

Comment: emm... style="display:none;" in html for divs 2 and 3? Or second class with display:none? See no reason to use JS for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID's should be named with a leading letter before the digit.

"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")." (W3C)

Answer (score 3):

To hide the div at the start set it's display property to none, you already have a mydivhide class applied to the divs, but that class isn't defined.

You should define it to set them hidden like so:

`.mydivhide {
    display: none
}​`

I've updated your fiddle to include that http://jsfiddle.net/BcFVv/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#pages div').not('[id=1]').hide();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wqtT5/

Answer (score 1):

Just add: `$("#pages div:not(#1)").css("display", "none");`​ outside of the main function.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/BcFVv/1

P.S. Please wait at least ten minutes after asking for my help with one of my answers before posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not duplicate HTML element IDs, or IDs that start with numeric values.

I've updated your JS Fiddle as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/benedict_w/BcFVv/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [tabs widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) from the [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com) library.

Here is how : http://jsfiddle.net/BcFVv/7/