# Implementing Jquery improperly?

Tags: jquery, local, jsfiddle

I am trying to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/BcFVv/2/

This is my local code, but it's not working properly:

Am I missing something? Implemented the library incorrectly? Wrapped the function incorrectly?

```
<!--- CSS --->
<style type="text/css">
    .mydivhide {
        display: none
    }​
</style>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<!--- JQUERY --->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#buttons a").click(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          $("#pages div").css("display", "none");
          $("#pages div#" + id + "").css("display", "block");
    });​
});​
</script>​​​​

<div id="buttons">
     <a href="#" id="1" class="mybutton myred">Div 1</a>
     <a href="#" id="2" class="mybutton myblue">Div 2</a>
     <a href="#" id="3" class="mybutton myblue">Div 3</a>
</div>

<div id="pages">
    <div id="1" class="mydivshow">1111</div>
    <div id="2" class="mydivhide">2222</div>
    <div id="3" class="mydivhide">3333</div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Might try moving your jQuery code inside the header.  Just move everything between the `<script></script>` tags inside the header tag.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in the fiddle. What is your requirement exactly . Show the corresponding div right ??

Comment: Don't give multiple elements the same id , even if they are different type of elements

Comment: jsfiddle uses the HTML5 doctype by default, which allows id's that start with numeric values. Try using an ID that starts with a letter instead.

Comment: I know it works fine in fiddle, but I am trying to get it to work locally, which it isn't. So I'm trying to find the problem in the code I pasted here.

Comment: Check for any errors in the console section by hitting the F12 button

Comment: @KevinB I just went through the id's and changed them to a1, a2, a3. Still isn't working!

Comment: I'm not surprised, with duplicate id's even the fiddle shouldn't be working.

Comment: Regardless what is allowed or not, unless jQuery is changing it will still only return you the first element with the matching id and not a set of elements as it does when using any other selector. So having multiple ids with the same value will cause your jQuery code to yield unexpected results. Also, jQuery does not like `.`in ids as it treats `.` as  a special case. If you plan on using jQuery then do not use `.` in ids and keep them unique even if HTML 5 or any other doctype says it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: first, **no two elements should have the same** `id`. Also, `id`**s cannot begin with a digit.**
[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/BcFVv/9/) a demo.

Comment: Both as stated in answers to the original question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432060/hiding-showing-divs-jquery/12432126#12432126

Comment: @Abraham What should I change the button and div id's to, so that I can achieve the same result as shown in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Your IDs are invalid - you will run into all sorts problems if you don't fix those first - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12432115/664125

Comment: @benedict_w So i've looked at your Jsfiddle, and used those exact Id's. The code still does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/benedict_w/BcFVv/3/

Comment: are you using firebug or chrome developer tools - set a break point and see what is happening in the code?

Comment: @abraham What i find interesting is that I have tried all the solutions posted here, and none are working on my local file. But they all work great on jsfiddle!

Comment: It was an unexpected token error, got it fixed, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the id's with Class and then try for the div's

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#buttons a").click(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(id)
          $("#pages div").hide();
          $("#pages div." + id).show();
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ms986/)

Comment: That looks great, but I copied it exactly into my local file and it still does not work. How frustrating!

Comment: @user1486934: Apply the logic, don't copy-paste. Copy-Paste is the number 1 reason for broken code :) Look at the working fiddle and re-factor your code to use that same logic. If you applied it right it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Made these fixes/improvements:

1. Made id values in the HTML be unique and not numeric.
2. Changed selectors to match new HTML id values
3. Switched to `.hide()` and `.show()` which are a lot simpler.
4. Simplified getting the id to not use jQuery since it is not useful.
5. Extract number from new button id so it can be used to identify the desired page.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JHK4a/

Here's the resulting code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#buttons a").click(function() {
             var id = this.id.replace("b", "");
             $("#pages div").hide();
             $("#p" + id).show();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="buttons">
     <a href="#" id="b1" class="mybutton myred">Div 1</a>
     <a href="#" id="b2" class="mybutton myblue">Div 2</a>
     <a href="#" id="b3" class="mybutton myblue">Div 3</a>
</div>

<div id="pages">
    <div id="p1" class="mydivshow">1111</div>
    <div id="p2" class="mydivhide">2222</div>
    <div id="p3" class="mydivhide">3333</div>
</div>​
```